# rsync unexpected remote arg: user@server:/path

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to use [this rsync backup script](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Rsync_backup) on my server. However, I get the following error (when the script tries to execute the following command:

```
$ rsync -ar --delete -vvv -e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_LAV.pub' --exclude='.*' looise-av.be@ssh.looise-av.be:/www/wp /mnt/hdd/LAV-backups/wp.0
Unexpected remote arg: looise-av.be@ssh.looise-av.be:/www/wp
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=1, file=main.c, line=1348): about to call exit(1)
```

Strangely enough, everything works fine if I copy-paste* that into my terminal and press enter. It only goes wrong when it's executed by the script.

What's wrong here? How can I fix this?

*copy-paste = echo the line in the script, and then copy paste it after running the script once.

Comment: From the error message `Unexpected remote arg: looise-av.be@ssh.looise-av.be:/www/wp` it seems you are using a hostname `looise-av.be` where a username is expected.

Comment: Hey @Thomas, yeah that seems weird but looise-av.be is actually the username as well as the domain name (that's how our web host manages its users).

Comment: I would get rid of the `-e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_LAV.pub'` and configure this in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file instead, where everything that uses ssh can have it automatically without special configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, that worked. Too bad I still don't know what went wrong for rsync. The reason I actually did not use this solution before is because I thought it wasn't working properly. Turns out I made a type in my ssh config. oops!

Comment: In a script, `OPT="'ssh -i <key_file>'"; rsync [options] -e $OPT <source> <dest>` fails, while `OPT="ssh -i <key_file>"; rsync [options] -e "$OPT" <source> <dest>` succeeds. The output via `echo` looks fine, but internally the quoting is handled differently. Using `set -x` before the command, `bash` (not `sh`) tells me the failing command is `+ rsync -n -avz -e ''\''ssh' -i '/home/mc2/.ssh/id_rsa'\''' ngksao@10.1.0.220:/dist/mc2/ /home/mc2/` - quite a mess of quotes!

Answer (score 1):

When using complex options which use quotes, don't use plain variables, but use arrays instead.

The following works me in a Bash backup script:

```
simple_options="-a -vi"
filters=(
    --filter 'protect _before-*'
    --filter 'protect lost+found'
    -F
)
#...
rsync ... $simple_options "${filters[@]}" ...
```

The script you link to seems to use only a plain variable:

```
    RSYNC_OPTS="-a --delete -q"
#...
rsync $RSYNC_OPTS $SOURCE_PATH/. $BACKUP_PATH/$SOURCE_BASE.0/.
```

It seems you just added your ssh option to it, which produced the quoting mess that @roger-dueck pointed to in his comment.

Use a Bash array instead, and then use it inside double-quotes because your `-e` argument contains spaces:

```
RSYNC_OPTS=(-a --delete -q -e 'ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_LAV.pub')
rsync "${RSYNC_OPTS[@]}" $SOURCE_PATH/. $BACKUP_PATH/$SOURCE_BASE.0/.
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the scripting language? Is it just a bash shell script? Keep an eye out for special characters in the scripting method of choice. It's possible something in your command is getting replaced.

If bash, store the whole string in a var and echo it out, is it the same? If its modified some special characters are seen and it gets modified. This gets me when running an escaped awk command in a bash script.

Unrelated, but rsync is best for maintaining data clones of source and dest directory. Probably not the best for backups in time. I'd recommend the following to maintain a clone that preserves properties and permissions, etc.
rsync –avz –delete-after

-a (archive, preserve permissions of data)
-v (verbose)
-z (compress)
-delete-after (waits until full file list is known prior to deleting data in dest directory that no longer exists in source)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Scripting language is bash, and I already did what you suggest (last line in original post). Any other ideas?
Also, I know rsync is best for clones but the script takes care of constructing "backup"-like functionality. For more info, click the link in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "winning solution" given and I had the same error, in my case I needed to escape a space character! I didn't see that here, so for the next one searching for a solution:

I copied a line from my rsnapshot.log .. in my config there was this element:

```
 --rsync-path="sudo rsync"
```

In my log it listed as:

```
 --rsync-path=sudo rsync
```

when I altered that part into:

```
 --rsync-path=sudo\ rsync
```

That same error you have was gone at my end.
Maybe you need to escape characters?
Maybe use a double quote (") instead of a single quote? (')